# How would I go about getting user input for python's built in "input" function in a self made python environment?

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, development-environment

I'm using a tkinter gui to supply chunks of code to a stack for my program to draw from and execute. the problem comes when I use python's built in "input" function. It requires input from the console and doesn't accept it from a tkinter supplied input. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

(Edit: I'm using python 3.5 through Anaconda on windows 10)

you can find the full code here:
https://github.com/uhDreamer/simplePythonEnv/blob/master/simpleEnv.py

(please don't judge the code/style too strongly, it's basically just for fun and to see what I can do.)

Honestly I don't even know what to start to fix this issue. I thought maybe redirecting stdin like I did with stdout but I couldn't really find anything that pertains to my particular problem.

```
while running:
    if self.stack:
        code = self.stack.pop()
        with stdoutIO() as out:
            try:
                exec(code)
            except Exception as e:
                gui.log(str(e))
            finally:
                self.addToHistory(code)
        gui.log(out.getvalue())
    else:
        time.sleep(.1)
```

I need the program to get its input from the next input posted through the tkinter gui, and wait for it if there isn't any.

Comment: Do you have something as part of your GUI that users input content to? If so, access that widgets attributes. Why redirect stdin?

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't seem to accept the input in that case.or the first line I do something like """x = input(">>> ")""" and i want to put something is like "54" for the input, but it doesn't really do anything when i do that

Comment: So you're trying to create your own console essentially

Comment: @pstatix basically. I'm not sure why but it's fun so I've just keep going at it

Comment: So having run your code and seen what it roughly does, why not do a check in the engine to see if the code requests `input()`, and set a flag when it does? Then you store a state and "mimic" the wait inside the text area and check for an Enter key press when done?

Comment: @pstatix I did what I could with your suggestion. I had thought of doing something like that before you mentioned it but had no idea how to implement it until you described the process. I'm not even sure I did it how you said, nor how I got it to work, but it does work now. Thanks for the help! (I updated it on github if you wanna see the changes)